# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else' formatting issue?

Tags: bash

I'm pretty new to bash and am having trouble with what I assume is formatting. I'm trying to edit the `/etc/profile` so it will display a login message for root and a different login message for anyone else. But I'm getting the error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else`. I've tried all the different combinations of no semicolon, then on the next line etc but always get the same error. I've tried the lines separately and they display fine (except `$HOSTNAME`, can't get that to work). When run like this and login with root it will just jump to "Welcome `$USER`...".

Anyone suggestions would be appreciated!

```
if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\033[40;37;7m Danger! Root is doing stuff in `pwd`\033[0m"
else
  echo "Welcome $USER! You are working on `$HOSTNAME` in `pwd`."
fi
```

Comment: It works for me with bash 3.2

Comment: Looks fine to me - and does work, despite two things. FIrst, you most likely meant to check for `[ "$UID" -eq 0 ]` instead of `-ne` - otherwise it's echoing the root thingy for non-root users and the way round. And second: `$HOSTNAME` must not be enclosed in backticks, it's no command.

Comment: @JohannesH.: Unless your hostname happens to be the same as some command (say, if you named your machine `cat`).

Comment: @Keith: Whilst possible, it's rather unlikely that this is what the OP intended to do :D

Comment: @JohannesH.: Agreed -- but there is a substantial risk of that line of code unexpectedly executing some seemingly random command.

Comment: @JohannesH. Oh awesome, just changing the -ne to -eq fixed it. Thank you :D. Also $HOSTNAME is in backticks, same as pwd but it doesn't work although pwd does.

Comment: Because `$HOSTNAME` is a variable expansion (like `$USER`, which is not in backticks but works ^^), while `pwd` is ac command that is executed in a subshell (which is done by surrounding it with backticks).

Comment: Oh right I read that wrong, sorry :P. Okay yes all working now :) Thank you so much JohannesH.!

Comment: Use `printf`. `/etc/profile` is intended to work in any POSIX-compatible shell, and the `-e` option to `echo` is a `bash` extension.

Answer (score 0):

As written, above works for me - but, as pointed out, you should change your test to `-eq 0`.

For the ***syntax error near unexpected token*** problem - I will guess that your file contains embedded 'control codes', i.e. most likely a carriage return `\r`.

Try:

```
cat -e ~/your_profile
```

see any non-printable characters?  if so, remove them (`cat` options may vary - check you manpage) or

```
od -c ~/your_profile
```